# Android studio (Intellij) keymap and closing bracet on Macosx

Tags: android, intellij-idea, keymapping

I encounter a problem on android studio on MacOSX.
When I want to close a brace ALT+) my cursor jump to bottom widget windows.
I have this problem on 2 macs and I can have closing brace on others application.
I suppose I have a problem on my Android Studio keymap but I can't find this shortcut in preferences.

If someone has a solution it will make my day.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found yet :

This is the shortcut for showing the Terminal.

You can remove it in `Preferencies -> Keymap -> Main menu -> View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal`